# Proving that addition on both sides preserves equality

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

I'm doing some very low level proofs in abstract algebra and I have derived the fact that (on a particular ring) $0 = -1$ where $0$ is the additive identity of the ring in question and $-1$ is the inverse of its multiplicative identity.

I wish to prove that this implies $0 = 1$ (which I can use to prove that my ring is the trivial ring) but I am struggling to do so.  Intuitively we can add $1$ to both sides and perform the following derivation

\begin{align*}
0 = -1 &\implies 0 + 1 = (-1) + 1 \tag{???} \\
&\implies 1 = (-1) + 1 \tag{Identity} \\
&\implies 1 = 0 \tag{Inverse} \\
\end{align*}

But I'm not really sure how to justify adding $1$ to both sides.  I believe the definition of equality on a ring has been inherited from set theory, however I can't figure out how one might prove this using the axioms of set theory.

How might I go about proving that $a = b \implies a+x = b+x$?  Is this something that is proven or is it derived from some definition somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question.  Are you just trying to show that $0 = -1$ implies that $0 = 1$?

Comment: Part of the definition of the definition of a ring is that the elements form an abelian group under $+$.  If you go back to the definition of a group (or the definition of a binary operation), you'll be able to show that $a = b \implies a + x = b + x$.

Comment: "I'm doing some very low level proofs in abstract algebra and I have derived the fact that 0=−1 where 0 is the additive identity of the ring in question and −1 is the inverse of its multiplicative identity."  Then you've done something wrong.

Comment: In a ring $(R,+,\cdot)$, we know (by definition) that $(R,+)$ is an abelian group (we don't really need the abelian part though, just that $R$ is a group w.r.t $+$), so $\forall~x\in R~\exists -x\in R~:~x+(-x)=0$ and hence $a=b\iff a+x=b+x~\forall~a,b,x\in R$

Comment: :"How might I go about proving that a=b⟹a+x=b+x? Is this something that is proven or is it derived from some definition somewhere? "  Is basic substitution of equality.  If a *IS* b then anything you do to a is the same thing as doing it to b because a *IS* b.  SO $a = b \implies a + x = b + x$.  That's a given.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't see anything in the usual definition of a ring that requires it to have more than one element. (If $0$ is the only element, then $0$ works as both the multiplicative and additive identity--everything comes out $0$ anyway).

Comment: @fleablood I'm working on a particular ring not a general ring.  I am attempting to prove that this ring must be the trivial ring.  If I had thought I had proven $0=-1$ in general I would as you said I had done something wrong.

Comment: Then 0=-1 => 0+1=-1+1 => 1=0.  Yes, you can assume a=b => a+x=b+x is a given.  That's what *equality* means.  So yes, this ring is trivial.  If a=a.1=a (1)=a.0=a(1-1)=a-a=0 for all a in the ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just because addition (and all binary operations, for that matter) are functions.

If $a=b$, then the ordered pair $(a,x)=(b,x)\in R\times R$.

By the definition of a function, $a+x=+(a, x)=+(b, x)=b+x$

Comment: I feel that some other answers offered (in comments too) are just exceedingly indirect or overcomplicated descriptions of this simple fact.

Answer (score 2):

Most traditional set theories imply the basic concepts of function and relation: a set is in most of the axiomatizations simply a relation. In particular 2 relations are usually considered fundamental: "is an element of" and "is equal to".

Ring axioms take for granted a certain set theory axiomatization with which they define the ring set and add to that 2 total binary functions (or 2 tertiary relations +(x,y,z) and *(x,y,z) whose meaning is self-explainatory I guess). But this isn't really relevant if I understand what you're doing.

Being the 2 ring actions just standard functions (i.e. non multi-valued) then:

(a + x = b &&  a + x = c) implies (b = c)

(a + x = b &&  b = c) implies (a + x = c)

(a + b = x &&  a + c = x) implies (b = c)

Etc... including of course your "both sides" theorem given the proper substitutions.